# Avoid JDBCTokenStore in spring Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I was creating a spring oath2 application. It works. I have a doubt.

Based on this URL http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html there are only 2 real options:
JdbcTokenStore, JwtTokenStore.

Is it possible to use JDBCTokenStore but not refer to it in the resourceServers?
I mean can we not have it referred directly only in the AuthorizationServer and the resource servers could use an endpoint from AuthorizationServer  instead of configuring another direct JDBCTokenStore reference.

Motive: Want to avoid sharing a database between AuthorizationServer  and multiple ResourceServers. Is there any other way to achieve this motive.

R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Resource Servers you can use [RemoteTokenServices](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/RemoteTokenServices.html). This class queries the /check_token endpoint present in Authorization Server to verify tokens.

You can have a database only for authentication server and another databases for your resource servers.

```
<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices">
    <property name="checkTokenEndpointUrl" value="${auth.service.url:https://localhost:8443/auth-service}/oauth/check_token"/>
    <property name="clientId" value="${auth.client.name:TEST_API}"/>
    <property name="clientSecret" value="${auth.client.secret:password}"/>
    <property name="accessTokenConverter" ref="accessTokenConverter"/>
    <property name="restTemplate" ref="oauth2RestTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: That sounds so perfect. Thanks. Will try and get back. This I think eliminates the need for the ResourceServices to keep any oauth / jwt information in its database. In fact the resource resvice could now use a database only if its funtionality needs a database. Right?